# Git - Commits from remote branch after pulling from local branch

Tags: git, version-control, git-merge, git-pull

I have a git repository on my local machine and on some of git online services.

And I have two **branches - branch1 and branch2**, both of them pushed to origin as branch1 and branch2.
 So, there is no difference between my local and remote repo.

Okay, I need (for my own reasons) to do 'git pull origin branch1' when I'm in branch2. And after that, after I'm asking for 'git status', I get message, that my local and remote branch2 are diverged and have XX and XX different commit(s) each other, and I need to 'git pull' and 'git push' before I can continue.

The question is - **how can this happen that my remote branch have some commits that needed to be pulled?**
 It is my own repo (so I'm 100% sure I'm only one who can commit here), and from my point of view there can only be one situation - remote branch hasn't commits that was pulled to its local copy. How can this happen? From where this commits are show up?

Comment: Can you show the latest commit graph by the command `git log --oneline --decorate --graph --all`?

Answer (score 0):

You must checkout your local branch1 before pull its remote changes:

```
git checkout branch1
git pull origin branch1
```

Without switching to branch1 the pull of the changes are pulled into branch2

Comment: Add to avoid such mistakes in the future, I recommend to just do `git pull origin`when you are on a tracked branch (most of the time) or just do `git fetch origin` before doing the merge or rebase itself

Comment: The most important thing to understand here is that you can't pull or merge or rebase a branch that you're not checkout first and point to.

Comment: Indeed, one of the 3 or 4 most important thing to understand when working with git...